# jQuery Tabs: doesn't work (doesn't change page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying the jQuery Tabs but i cannot make them work.

I have this HTML code:

```
<!-- / NAVIGATORE / -->
<div class="navigator windowtemplate movingwindow">
  <div class="top">Navigatore <a href="#"><span class="closebutton closedialog"></span></a></div>

    <!-- Menu -->
  <div class="navi_menu">
    <a href="#navi-public"><span class="selected">Stanza Pubbliche</span></a><a href="#navi-private"><span>Stanze Private</span></a><a href="#navi-me"><span>Mie</span></a><a href="#navi-search"><span>Cerca</span></a>
  </div>

  <div class="body">
     <!-- Stanze Pubbliche -->
     <div class="public" id="navi-public">
       <div class="list scrollbar">
         <ul>
         <a href="#"><li>Stanza scema <span class="usersinroom red">50</span></li></a>
       </ul>
       </div>
     </div>

     <!-- Stanze Private -->
     <div class="private" id="navi-private">
       <div class="list scrollbar">
         <ul>
         <a href="#"><li>Stanza scema <span class="usersinroom red">50</span></li></a>
         <a href="#"><li>Stanza ancora più scema <span class="usersinroom orange">47</span></li></a>
       </ul>
       </div>
     </div>

     <!-- Mie stanze -->
     <div class="me" id="navi-me">
       <div class="list scrollbar">
         <ul>
         <a href="#"><li>Stanza scema <span class="usersinroom red">50</span></li></a>
         <a href="#"><li>Stanza ancora più scema <span class="usersinroom orange">47</span></li></a>
         <a href="#"><li>Stanza scema <span class="usersinroom orange">40</span></li></a>
       </ul>
       </div>
     </div>

     <!-- Cerca -->
     <div class="search" id="navi-search">
       <div class="list scrollbar">
         <ul>
         <a href="#"><li>Stanza scema <span class="usersinroom red">50</span></li></a>
         <a href="#"><li>Stanza ancora più scema <span class="usersinroom orange">47</span></li></a>
         <a href="#"><li>Stanza scema <span class="usersinroom orange">40</span></li></a>
         <a href="#"><li>Stanza ancora più scema <span class="usersinroom yellow">35</span></li></a>
       </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom"></div>

</div>
```

And this jQuery script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    // setup ul.tabs to work as tabs for each div directly under div.panes
    $("span.navi_menu").tabs("div.body > div");
});
</script>
```

But this seems to not work, where i'm wrong? :(

(Sorry if this would be a stupid thing, but i'm newbie with jQuery, so i don't already know good this language).

Comment: Are you remembering to include both jQuery and jQuery UI?

Comment: What's so obvious about it? You didn't include the code you're using to include those files, or a link to an example, so it's not obvious to me.

Comment: Anyway, i'm using this library:

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js

(nevermind the fact that I'm using 2 different CDN, it's just a test)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector is looking for a `span` while your `navi_menu` element is a `div`. Also, don't use a selector inside the tabs method, JQuery-UI plugins expect a method name. Your JavaScript should be:

```
 $("span.navi_menu").tabs();
```

And your HTML had some issues. You need to make sure you're structuring it very similar to how JQuery-UI tabs expects you to. That means wrapping your tabs in `<li>` tags and wrapping those in a `<ul>` tag. Follow the documentation here: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/

Here's a sample template with some of the HTML you've included, you should be able to reinsert your HTML from there: [Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/cm4PU/3/)

Comment: I've just tryied:     $("div.navi_menu").tabs("div.body > div"); but nothing, i get this error: Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on tabs prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'div.body > div'

Comment: Don't use a selector inside the tabs plugin call. That's the way JQuery-ui allows people to access public functions to the plugin. There's a couple things wrong with your HTML as well. I'll add a basic template to the answer so you can add all your HTML back in.